# Creating FTP user to access a specific directory with SFTP in Linux Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, user-management

I'm creating an FTP user on Linux Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, but when I try to log in via FileZilla with SFTP I get the following error:

```
Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
```

If I try to connect with my root user everything's fine, so I must have missed something in the new user creation. Here's what i did:

First of all I created a fake shell in /etc/shells naming it /bin/false
I create a group named ftpgroup

```
sudo groupadd ftpgroup
```

Then I created the ftp user within it

```
sudo useradd --home /var/www/html/mydir --group ftpgroup --shell /bin/false myftpuser
```

I gave a password to the user

```
sudo passwd myftpuser
```

And made it the owner of the home directory i gave him

```
sudo chown -R myftpuser /var/www/html/mydir
```

finally I set up privileges for the folder

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/mydir
```

I'm aware that changing the /bin/false shell to /bin/bash would make it work, but that would give my user the ability to access shell commands, which I would avoid if possible, I just want him to access files in his own directory and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Change the owner of your /var/www/html/mydir with below command

```
sudo chown -R root:ftpgroup /var/www/html/mydir
```

check this one for reference
http://devtidbits.com/2011/06/29/implement-a-sftp-service-for-ubuntudebian-with-a-chrooted-isolated-file-directory/

Answer (score 0):

You could modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` a bit and use

```
Match User myftpuser
   ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   PermitTunnel no
   X11Forwarding no
```

Of course, replace `username` with the username you'd like to restrict. It's also possible to match against user group with `Match Group` parameter.

Anyway, after that modification and reloading your ssh server config it should work.

Comment: I tried your solution, but if I leave ChrootDirectory %h I can't access, I get a "Network error: Software caused connection abort". Without that line it works, but I'm able to access parent directory, which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Since you have only one user to match against, try `ChrootDirectory /home/myftpuser` or so. Also check out the directory permissions.

Comment: Same behaviour. The user owns the directory, and permission are 777.